# Delegate method of push notification is not hitting after few hours

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, ios8, push-notification

I am sending silent push notification for my ipad for every hour. But after few hours the delegate method is not hitting(I have put a local notification inside delegate method).I am using this 
**application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:** delegate method to handle silent push notification. When i reset ipad under settings and try to send push notification, the delegate method will hit and work as i expected. I am not understanding this behaviour. I have also put sound to my notification,which plays when notification reaches device.But delegate inside my app is not hitting.My delegate code is as below.

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    //some database operations


    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Comment: How and where are you handling incoming push notifications? Inside `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` do you have something like, `if ([app applicationState] == UIApplicationStateInactive) { //...do something }`

Answer (score 2):

```
1.APNS is based on Apple Servers, and Apple doesn't give any guarantee on successful message delivery.
2.If the app is open (i.e. the user is using the app) while the notification arrives, iOS doesnt show a notification message, you need to handle it.
3.Notification shows up only when the app is backgrounded or killed.
4.Also implement feedback service on your server side; will help you get rid of old unwanted tokens(users who deleted the app or disabled notifications thru settings).
5..Dont send too many notifications to a device within a short span of time, coz APNS caches only 1 message/device (if the device is offline). So it can deliver the message when the device comes online. Am not sure how long the message is cached though.
```

**Some Notifications Received, but Not All**

If you are sending multiple notifications to the same device or computer within a short period of time, the push service will send only the last one.

Here's why. The device or computer acknowledges receipt of each notification. Until the push service receives that acknowledgment, it can only assume that the device or computer has gone off-line for some reason and stores the notification in the quality of service (QoS) queue for future redelivery. The round-trip network latency here is of course a major factor.

As described in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide, the QoS queue holds a single notification per app per device or computer. If the service receives another notification before the one in the queue is sent, the new notification overwrites the previous one.

All of this points out that the intent is that a notification indicates to an app that something of interest has changed on the provider, and the app should check in with the provider to get the details. Notifications should not contain data which isn't also available elsewhere, and they should also not be stateful.

Any push notification that isn't delivered immediately was queued for future redelivery because your device was not connected to the service. "Immediately" of course needs to take latency for your connection into account. Outlying cases would be beyond 60 seconds as APNs will time out at that point.

[APNS Technical Note TN2265](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html)

Comment: I went through your mentioned stuff. But i am not getting, why sometimes app will be awaken through notification, but sometimes not? Whether push notification hits delegate method every time, when it reaches device OR it depends on OS to awake the app?

Comment: Apple doesn't give any guarantee on successful message delivery APNS
.